# how to slice list in cython

Tags: python, list, cython, slice

I have a list in cython and want to slice it without using python object ( for speed ).

```
cdef int len = 100    
cdef int *q
cdef int *r

q = <int *>malloc( len *cython.sizeof(int) )

r = q[50:]
```

and a got this error:

```
r = q[50:]
    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

hello.pyx:24:9: Slicing is not currently supported for 'int *'.
```

There a efficient way to do it? The "... not currently supported..." scare me a bit.
I use cython 0.18

Comment: `q` isn't a list but a native array. I'm guessing you'll have to use something lower-level to work with those. (Pass around an array and a start+end index.)

Comment: @millimoose I take a look on the memoryview stuff in doc but I'm not be able to make it working with my simple example. I'm new with cython and C programming. What did you mean want you talking about lower-level and "Pass around an array and a start+end index" ? thanx

Comment: In C, when you're working with arrays, you usually don't just use the array, but a `start` and `length` parameter to indicate what part of the array a function is supposed to work on. The array and the two indices together represent a "slice". (You can see this if you look at some example code for quicksort for instance.) That said, this might be terribly overkill for Cython, which I'm not terribly familiar with.

Comment: @millimoose And can you tell me where I can find example code for quicksort? It's exactly why I need to slice my array , for making many qsort for implementation of a KDtree ( I already did it in python but need to transfert it cython for speed )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast slicing and some other cool stuff is possible via Typed Memoryviews. But in order to do slicing you need some metadata about your arrays, so it's better to use array types instead of plain pointers. Look up the docs for more info: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html.

A modification of your problem gives:

```
cdef int q_array[5] # c array
cdef int[:] q # 1D memview
cdef int[:] r # another 1D memview

q = q_array # point q to data
r = q[2:] # point r to a slice of q

r[0] = 5 # modify r

# test                                                                      
print q[2]
print r[0]
```

You can still create pointers from the slices, if you really want it bad:

```
# ...

cdef int* r_ptr
cdef int* q_ptr

r_ptr = &r[0]
q_ptr = &q[0]

print q_ptr[2]
print r_ptr[0]
```

Also works with numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

cdef int[:] q = np.arange(100).astype('int32') # slow
cdef int[:] r

r = q[50:] # fast slicing

print r[0]
```

Comment: Ok , your example help me to understand a bit more how memview work for slicing array. But I get a error when I try to compile any code with a memview declaration. Everytime I add a line like : cdef int[:] r

Comment: I compile it as descripted in the doc of cython. Standard setup.py and I use gcc (MinGW) on windows 7 64bit. Here is a part of the error ( too long ) : build\temp.win32-3.3\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x1032): undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_sub_4'
build\temp.win32-3.3\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x21e5): undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_add_4'
build\temp.win32-3.3\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0xa3d0): undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_sub_4'
collect2: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: hm... the error could be on the pyx-->c stage. Does everything go smooth when you fire "cython -a hello.pyx" ?

Comment: I post the error on the mailgroup of cython and they thinking thissound like a bug probably with Python 3.3 . Because it's seem to working with python 2.7. What version are you using ? Me : Python 3.3 with cython 0.18 and MinWG GCC 4.6.2

Comment: Oh, I see, that may well be a Py3k issue... I'm using Python-2.7 under Linux, never tried with python 3.